# How can I iterate through a data frame and create folders as columns in the df and subfolders as rows in the df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is the code I got:

```
prod_lst = getprod()
prod_df = pd.DataFrame(prod_lst, columns = ['Client'])
for i, j in prod_df.iterrows():
  print(i, j)
  path = '../models/' + i + '/' + j
  isExist = os.path.exists(path)
  if not isExist:
      os.makedirs(path)
```

```
  Client

0 OTT

1 DVD

2 OTV
```

I need a directory like:

```
Client

OTT

DVD

OTV
```

Comment: The indentation is inconsistent. E.g., the line with "os.makedirs(path)" is indented with four spaces. Is this in the original code?

Comment: OK, the OP may not be coming back (*"Last seen more than a month ago"*).

Answer (score 1):

[`DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) produces "(index, Series) pairs." Meaning that `j` is a Series of values representing the row from the DataFrame. To access a specific value from `Client` we'll need to select the value from the Series:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Sample DF
prod_df = pd.DataFrame([['OTT'], ['DVD'], ['OTV']], columns=['Client'])
# Column to Select
col = 'Client'
# Iterate over rows
for idx, row in prod_df.iterrows():
    path = f'../models/{col}/{row[col]}'
    exists = os.path.exists(path)
    if not exists:
        os.makedirs(path)
```

Alternatively, if we do not need all the values from the row we can iterate over just the `Client` column instead:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Sample DF
prod_df = pd.DataFrame([['OTT'], ['DVD'], ['OTV']], columns=['Client'])
# Loop Over Just the Client Column
col = 'Client'
# Loop Over values in just the column
for value in prod_df[col]:
    path = f'../models/{col}/{value}'
    exists = os.path.exists(path)
    if not exists:
        os.makedirs(path)
```

The folder creation logic could also be simplified with [`Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) from `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

# Sample DF
prod_df = pd.DataFrame([['OTT'], ['DVD'], ['OTV']], columns=['Client'])
# Loop Over Just the Client Column
col = 'Client'
for value in prod_df[col]:
    Path(f'../models/{col}/{value}').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method that is working; not sure if it is the best practice.

```
for value, rows in prod_df.itertuples():
    
    path = '../models/' + prod_df.columns[0] + '/' + rows
    isExist = os.path.exists(path)
    if not isExist:
        os.makedirs(path)
```